# Routes broken in production, but not in development with Pyramid

Tags: python, debugging, routes, pyramid

I have a specific route ('service' and '/service') that doesn't work (they trigger the NotFound view) in production (under Apache 2 and mod_wsgi).

However, in development they work fine.

What can I do to debug this issue? I've tried adding another similar route (throws a configuration error). I've tried running it under the development.ini file (no change except for logging).

Answer (score 2):

You might try to use Pyramid's notfound debug output to gather the differences between your production configuration and your development configuration:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/environment.html#debugging-not-found-errors